# In a Ridge regression, why do i get a stronger shrinkage when i remove some coefficients from the penalization term?

Tags: regularization, ridge-regression

I cannot understand why in a ridge regression if I remove some coefficients from the penalty term I have a stronger shrinkage of the remaining coefficients that are included in the penalty term.

From the data I obtain I believe this statement, but I cannot understand how this happens.  Because the lambda tuning parameter is fixed and multiplied over the sum of squares of the coefficients, so the only difference is that the penalty term will be smaller (since instead of 5 coefficients I will have only 3).

Comment: Are the regressors correlated?

Comment: Sparsity and shrinkage are two different things. I have edited your title accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If the regressors are correlated**, then this may have large influences.

A particular regressor whose penalty is removed, may 'take over' a part of the role of other regressors that still have the penalty if that regressor is correlated.

An extreme (and simple) example is when two regressors are exactly the same. If both are penalized, then they well share fifty-fifty of the fit. However, when you penalize only one, then the unpenalized will fit the observations completely and the penalized will be zero (hence an increase of the shrinking for the penalized regressor).

Note that the shrinking can both decrease and increase. It depends on whether the correlation is positive or negative.

---

However, **if the regressors are uncorrelated**, then the penalties on other terms have no influence.

Note that the solution of ridge regression has an explicit solution

$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX + \lambda I)^{-1} X^Ty$$

And the inverse of a diagonal matrix is a diagnal matrix with the entries inversed. The solution for a specific coëfficiënt will be

$$\hat{\beta}_i = \frac{X_i \cdot y}{X_i \cdot X_i + \lambda_i}$$

And this is only dependent on the penalty term $\lambda_i$ relating to the specific coëfficiënt and not the penalties on other coëfficiënts.

Comment: +1 but IMO its the second point that could be clarified and expanded (exactly same-> coefficient shared between them vs removing penalisation on one coefficient)

Comment: I don't follow / am not convinced by the paragraph preceding the section split, but the second section is great. I suspect that if the features are independent (and of unit variance?), then OP's intuition holds...

Comment: @BenReiniger you are right. I took another look at it, and tried to give a more solid proof, and I must say that my intuition was wrong.

Comment: Actually, the intuition was not too bad, it is just not working when the regressors are perpendicular.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I asked the question because I read that removing the penalization on regressors that you expect to appear in the model is a good practice, yet I didn't understand why the stronger shrinkage happened and what it implied. I am new to ML so i always doubt that if what i am doing leads to a correct result.